# Number sequence recognition

Tags: r

developing on from another question:

[Identifying sequences of repeated numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509381/identifying-sequences-of-repeated-numbers-in-r/15328802#15328802)

I have used the answers from that question to identify sequences within my data, not a problem, however I am stuck when it comes to identifying sequences of differing numbers, for example: the sequence maybe: 126,126,25 rather than repetitive numbers,

The code I am currently using is the same as in the above question (rle)

sample data:

```
   d<-read.table(text='Date.Time Aerial
794  "2012-10-01 08:18:00"      1
795  "2012-10-01 08:34:00"      1
796  "2012-10-01 08:39:00"      1
797  "2012-10-01 08:42:00"      1
798  "2012-10-01 08:48:00"      1
799  "2012-10-01 08:54:00"      1
800  "2012-10-01 08:58:00"      1
801  "2012-10-01 09:04:00"      1
802  "2012-10-01 09:05:00"      1
803  "2012-10-01 09:11:00"      1
1576 "2012-10-01 09:17:00"      2
1577 "2012-10-01 09:18:00"      2
804  "2012-10-01 09:19:00"      1
805  "2012-10-01 09:20:00"      1
1580 "2012-10-01 09:21:00"      2
1581 "2012-10-01 09:23:00"      2
806  "2012-10-01 09:25:00"      1
807  "2012-10-01 09:32:00"      1
808  "2012-10-01 09:37:00"      1
809  "2012-10-01 09:43:00"      1', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=1)
```

code that will recognise repeated sequence of numbers (same number repeated 4 times):

```
tmp <- rle(d$Aerial)
d$newCol <- rep(tmp$lengths>=4, times = tmp$lengths)
```

However I do not know how to identify a sequence which contains different numbers, for example the sequence may be:   1,2,2,1 (as in d$Aerial) at "2012-10-01 09:11:00"

There are various patterns. The data is detections of a signal at a given time on a given Aerial, but to keep the question open I have simplified it as above. so the pattern is 1,2,2,1 i.e. detection at Aerial 1, then 2, then, 2, then 1 (in the Aerial column). In my data when this pattern occurs it indicates a behavioural movement of an animal. If I am able to identify it, I can then perform more calculations on it.

The code above indicates when a number is repeated 4 times, however it is unable to identify repetition of 4 numbers which are different from each other: 1,2,2,1

This sequence (1,2,2,1) may come up multiple times in the data and I would like to identify it each time.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me yet. Could you elaborate with a proper example... and how it is different from that post? You should *really take time* to formulate your question if you expect good answers.

Comment: Maybe a description of the problem you're trying to solve will help clarify things... Do you have a set of patterns you're looking for?  How do you determine them?

Comment: You've given us data. Good! But *your problem* is still not clear yet. I think you're looking for transitions from number 1 to 2, 2 to 1, 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 at positions 11, 13, 15, 17? If so, try this: `which(c(0, diff(d$Aerial)) != 0)` (or `head(cumsum(rle(d$Aerial)$lengths)+1, -1)`). If not, please edit your question again to explain it clearer.

Comment: there are various patterns, the data is detections of a signal at a given time on a given Aerial, but to keep the question open i have simplified it as above, so the pattern is 1,2,2,1 i.e. detection at Aerial 1, then 2, then, 2, then 1 (in the Aerial column). In my data when this pattern occours it indicates a behavioural movement of an animal. If i am able to identify it i can then perform more calculations on it

Comment: So, after the first time `c(1, 2, 2, 1)` appears, any more occurrences of `c(1, 2, 2, 1)` should be treated as a "repeated sequence"? It seems like unless you have some more constraints, you'll have to identify every 4+ length sequence in your data, and search for repeats of them. My suspicion is that the search space for this will be so huge it's going to be impossible without more constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brute-force solution:

```
pat <- c(1,2,2,1)
x <- sapply(1:(nrow(d)-length(pat)), function(x) all(d$Aerial[x:(x+length(pat)-1)] == pat))

d[which(x),]  # "which" prevents recycling of the shorter vector "x"
##               Date.Time Aerial
## 803 2012-10-01 09:11:00      1
## 805 2012-10-01 09:20:00      1
```

`zoo` has `rollapply` which can be used for this:

```
require(zoo)
x <- rollapply(d$Aerial, length(pat), FUN=function(x) all(x == pat))

d[which(x),]
##               Date.Time Aerial
## 803 2012-10-01 09:11:00      1
## 805 2012-10-01 09:20:00      1
```

For the (now deleted) comment, to find the rows which match the final character of the pattern:

```
d[which(x)+length(pat)-1,]
##               Date.Time Aerial
## 804 2012-10-01 09:19:00      1
## 806 2012-10-01 09:25:00      1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what the patterns are going to be in advance (which is what I initially took from your question), then here's a brute force solution that will find repeated patterns of a given length:

```
pattern_length = 4
patterns = list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(d) - pattern_length)) {
  patterns[[i]] = d$Aerial[i:(i + pattern_length - 1)]
}
unique(patterns[duplicated(patterns)])

[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 2 1

[[4]]
[1] 2 2 1 1
```

You could then feed these into Matthew Lundberg's answer.

Comment: ah i see! thanks, yes i already know the pattern as the pattern implies a specific behaviour!