# Parsing out all repeat and consecutive numbers in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
1360    C   0   403
1361    A   0   403
1362    G   0   403
1402    0   A   444
2019    T   0   1060
2020    T   0   1060
2021    G   0   1060
2022    T   0   1060
2057    T   0   1085
2062    0   A   1093
2062    0   C   1094
2062    0   C   1095
```

Desired Output

```
1402    0   A   444
2057    0   0  1085
```

I was trying to parse out all the rows with repeats or consecutive numbers in the column 1. So, I want only the rows with the numbers which were not a repeat number or a consecutive number in the dataset. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `df[c(TRUE,diff(df[,1])>1) & c(diff(df[,1])>1,TRUE),]`, where `df` is your `data.frame`.

Comment: this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509381/identifying-sequences-of-repeated-numbers-in-r

Comment: Thanks so much Nicola for your help! I tried the code. It does pick up some of the rows but misses out several in between. For example, it picks up the first one´1402` and then the next one 2430, but it doesn't pick up 2540 and 2571. A small snippet of the dataset is below.
1360,1361,1362,1402,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028, 2029,2030, 2062,2062,2062,2062,2430,2540, 2571.
Any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: Nicola, your code worked very well too. Thanks a lot for your help! It was looking in the first column in my dataset as opposed to the second column. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff` to find the difference between adjacent elements in a vector. Assuming the vector is sorted, `diff` will return zero for repeat numbers and one for consecutive numbers.

```
keep1 <- diff(df[,1]) > 1
```

This will include values that are after a jump, but at the start of a new sequence, so we need to check the lag1 value, and pad the logical vector to make it as long as the original.

```
keep <- c(keep1, TRUE) & c(TRUE, keep1)
df[keep,]
```

Comment: Thank you Richard for your help. The code is picking up some of the numbers and missing out some, like I mentioned with the code that Nicola had posted. It seems to be missing some of those numbers and picking some. Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: works for me `x<-c(1360,1361,1362,1402,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028, 2029,2030, 2062,2062,2062,2062,2430,2540, 2571);
 keep1 <- diff(x)>1;
 keep <- c(keep1, TRUE) & c(TRUE, keep1);
 x[keep];
[1] 1402 2430 2540 2571`

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. The code worked. It was my mistake, I forgot to change the column number and it was referring to a preceding column in my dataset.

Comment: Using named columns is much safer. Something like `df$myColumn`